# Angular show previous and next value by ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have simple ngFor in which I am showing title like this

```
        title = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4" "t5", "t6"];

        <div *ngFor="let x of work; let i = index" (click)="changeindex(i)">
            <div>
                {{x.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I need to do is in ngFor it will show t1, t2 and t3 only. once I click on t3 then it will show t2, t3, and t4. Mean 1 previous and 1 next array. and if I click on t2 then it will show t1, t2, and t3

Comment: `LazyVGrid` always resizes spacing between horizontal items to fit the parent width. Use `HStack { VStack {} }` to change spacing between items.

Comment: what do you mean by saying show? Do you mean highlight or you will need to hide all elements and show only 3 elements at a time? And what is the expected result if you click on `t1`

Comment: lol this was for answering the previous question look at the post edit

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan hide all elements only first three will show and if t1 click nothing will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a combination of `*ngFor` / `*ngIf`.

Use a `<ng-container>` if you want to avoid unnecessary divs in the template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of work; let i = index" >
  <div *ngIf="i >= selected -1 && i <= selected+1" (click)="selected = i">
    <div>
      {{x.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

In .ts define

```
index=0;
title = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4" "t5", "t6"];
```

In your .html

```
<div *ngFor="let x of title |slice:index:(index+2)" 
      (click)="index<title.length-2 && index=index+1">
{{x}}
</div>
```

See that I use the construction `(click)="condition && action"`. So, if the condition is not fulfilled, not execute the action.

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Previous value: `title[i-1];`
and For next value: `title[i+1];`

example:
In your TS file :

```
changeindex(i) {
    const previousVaule  = title[i-1];
    const Next Value = title[i+1];
    const CurrentValue = title[i];

    // your nessseary code
}
```